# Datagridview Cell selected value insert into sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with datagridview tools so i am getting data from other form datagridview in first form datagridview and insert data into sqlserver database from first form datagridview.
First form datagridview column names are 
ItemName,quantity,amount etc,which are get from other form datagridview now i want to insert Itemcode against ItemName column from first datagridview rows but i am unable to do this.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ActiveControl == dataGridView1 && dataGridView1.CurrentCell == dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0]) // datagridview first cell enter event
        {
            ItemList fc = new ItemList() { OwnerForm = this }; 
            fc.ShowDialog(this);
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value = ItemName;
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = Item_MRP;
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = Item_Purchase;

               }
    }
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try { 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mateenwin;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand commandd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(Pur_Invoice_No)+1  FROM purchase", conn);
        int InvoiceNo = Convert.ToInt32(commandd.ExecuteScalar());

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.IsNewRow) continue;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=mateenwin; User id=sa; password=123");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Insert into purchase (Pur_Invoice_No,Pur_Payment_Type_ID, Supplier_Bill_No,Supplier_ID,Item_Code,Pur_Item_Batch_No,Item_Batch_Expiry,Pur_Item_PackQuantity,Purchase_Pack_Price,Discount_Percentage,Extra_Discount_Percentage,MRP_Final,Login_ID,Pur_Entry_Date) values ('" + InvoiceNo + "','" + this.comboBox1.SelectedValue + "','" + this.textBox2.Text + "','" + this.comboBox2.SelectedValue + "','" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value + "','" + row.Cells[5].Value + "','" + row.Cells[6].Value + "','" + row.Cells[7].Value + "','" + row.Cells[4].Value + "','" + this.comboBox3.Text + "',  GetDate())", con);
            con.Open();


            using (con)
            {

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
            MessageBox.Show("Invoice successfully Saved");
            dataGridView1.Focus();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and utilize paramterized queries and how they prevent sql injection. Your code is a textbook example of sql injection vulnerability. And then you need to read about the identity property in sql server. When you calculate your own like you are doing you have potential concurrency issues.Last but not least, you should put your connection string in a config file instead of hard coding it all over the place.

Comment: Probably should read this too http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Comment: Is this really a textbook example of SQL Injection, given its not a web application?

Comment: @Mr.B sql injection is NOT limited to web applications. The code is just as vulnerable. It is probably less likely to be affected but that does not mean the code is less vulnerable. The thinking that just because it is not a web site doesn't mean you should parameterize queries is dangerous. What happens when it gets converted to a website? You have to change all the queries? Not parameterizing queries is irresponsible and lazy in my opinion. It is so easy to do it right that doing it wrong is negligent.

Comment: So, what happens when you run this? If an error, show error message. If not, what does or does not happen? Define "unable to do this". And please heed the advice above - make param queries, both because of injection and for readability, auto quoting of strings, etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inputing the variables as you do now. It would be better and safer to add them as Parameters like this

```
command.Parameters.Add("@parameterName", SqlDbType.CharOrWhateverType).Value = variable;
```

And modify your SqlQuery like this

```
"Insert into purchase (Pur_Invoice_No) values (@parameterName)"
```

If it fails again please provide information about the exception you are getting.